# Intern functional tests on Chrome not scrolling to elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests, intern

I've got a HTML page that I want to run tests on. The page consists of a grid of boxes, and each box goes to a different page. I want my tests to click on each one, verify the destination exists and then go back to the main page to repeat.

The tests run fine until it reaches the boxes that go outside of the current window, and then returns that the element is not clickable at any point.

This error does not happen in Internet Explorer which scrolls the page down to the elements, and only happens on Chrome for me.

So my question is how can I make Chrome act like IE and scroll down to the element to click it?

Here is an example of one of my tests:

```
bdd.it("blah", function() {
  return remote
    .get(main page url)
    .findByLinkText("blah")
    .click()
    .getCurrentUrl()
    .then(function(url) {
        expect(url).to.equal("url to match against")
    });
});
```

As I mentioned these tests run fine until the elements are below the window.

Comment: Do you have a fixed header or footer (a container that is not moving if you scroll the page) ?

Comment: No, all of the elements scroll with the page.

Comment: It's hard to say without a reproducible example. It could be due to an animation. Try to add a delay or move to another element on the lower-right before the click. Also make sure that the window is not too small.

Comment: give a screenshot of your page.

Comment: @FlorentB moving the mouse to the lower right of the window does not seem to scroll the page down. Also, the elements extend below the visible bounds of the window and even making the window fullscreen wouldn't fit all of the boxes in, so making sure that the window is big enough won't help.

Comment: @yong unfortunately due to the nature of the work I can't provide a screenshot, but the page is a fluid grid of about 50 fixed-width boxes that flow to the next row down if they cannot fit in horizontally.

Comment: So if there are many cell in the grid, the grid will display a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Yes, except the cells make the grid's height increase, so that the window displays a vertical scroll bar, not the grid itself.

Comment: The driver scrolls the element at the bottom-left of the screen if the center point in not visible. In your case, it seems that this operation is failing. Try to see if it's the case by executing `$0.scrollIntoView()` in the console after inspecting the targeted element. If it's the case, you'll have to call `executeScript` to set the `scrollLeft` and  `scrollTop` property on the container with the scroll bar.

Comment: Hi Garvey,  There is a know issue on chromedriver-2.30.exe, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1852 .  it will lead failure on every click which click on an element not visible in current viewport.  Check your chromedriver version is 2.30 or not.  2.32 fixed the issue try 2.32